# Running Java Applet on Ubuntu in 16.04

Tags: java, icedtea

I'm trying to run Java applet on ubuntu 16.04 chrome and firefox browsers.  After googling online I see suggestions to install 'icedtea'.  Even after that I'm still not able to run java applet as i get the following message on in both chrome and firefox:

> Your browser is ignoring the  tag!

Obviously the message might be tailed by the application/applet that is trying to run but the point is that I can't make it work with icedtea.  Do I need chromium?  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Browsers these days don't support Java.

Comment: What about Web Start Apps in Java Console? Is it possible to allow Java in these conditions?